# Refreshing or updating of JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I want to develop a program that presents a slideshow of images using `JLabel`s.
Whenever I display a single image it works fine . My problem is that when I load image paths in an array they aren't displayed on to the `JLabel`:
refreshing or updating of `JLabel` doesn't work.

Here is my code that displays the function where i find something wrong

```
private ActionListener action = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (count == imgNames.size()) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        JLabel temp = new JLabel();
        temp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgNames.get(count)));
        picLabel = temp ;
        add(picLabel);
        System.out.println("Count "+ count);
        count++;
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
};
```

Where the `timer` is set up as follows:

```
timer = new Timer(2000, action);
timer.start();
```

Comment: Why do you remove and add a label instead of simply changing its icon? Anyway, if you want us to help, post a complete minimal example that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake -- remove()!!

Answer (score 1):

The ans to the above problem has been solved. This is very simple. Use ImageIcon[] that is an array instead of getting strings(FILE NAMES) and then giving it to the setIcon method , because this doesn't refresh or update image on jLabel.. so its better to use this way.
I don't know the cause of this answer . If anyone knows please post it so that others and I will be helpful to the topic.